# Laravel filter database from controller

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to make simple filter for indexing in my view with `<option>`. in default, the index view will show all of the data, but i want to make the view show the data based on the filter i made and show it in the same page.

this is the index (include the `<option>`) view

```
<form method="get" action="/">
  <select name="tag" id="tag_select">
      <option value=""> -pilih- </option>
      <option value="diproses">diproses</option>
      <option value="selesai">selesai</option>
  </select>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/tag.js') }}" charset="utf-8"></script>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="cek">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="get">
  </form>

<?php foreach ($blogs as $blog ): ?>
   <tr><td><b>Tanggal: </b></td><td>{{ $blog -> created_at}}</td><br>
   <tr><td><b>SI: </b></td><td>{{ $blog -> sistem}}</td><br>
   <tr><td><b>Subjek:</b></td><td><a href="/{{ $blog -> id}}"> {{ $blog -> title }}</a></td></tr> 
   <br>
   <tr><td><b>Oleh: </b></td><td>{{ $blog -> nama}}</td></tr> <br>
   <tr><td><b>Status: </b></td><td>{{ $blog -> tag}}</td></tr> <br> // i want to filter the data based on this
   <hr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

this is the filter method

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{

  $blogs = DB::table('blogs')->where('tag', $request -> tag)->get();
  return view('koding', ['blogs' => $blogs]);

}
```

in addition this is my index controller with it's route

```
Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@admin')->name('admin');
```

.

```
  public function admin()
{
  $blogs = blog::paginate(10);
  return view('koding', ['blogs' => $blogs]);
}
```

can you guys tell me what's wrong and what's the route for the filter method? thanks

Comment: where is the route for filter action.

Comment: You can add route of filter method

Comment: where is the route for filter method?

Comment: that is what i'm asking. i dont know how to write the filter route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try it

```
public function admin(Request $request)
{
  $blogs = blog::when($request->tag, function ($query, $tag) {
    return $query->where('tag', $tag);
  })->paginate(10);
  return view('koding', ['blogs' => $blogs]);
}
```

Comment: sorry but, it did't work, maybe you can suggest me the route?? (HomeController@filter)

Comment: no, you should use this route ```Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@admin')->name('admin');```